# I cant compile psych engine because of this error

Tags: haxe, lime-haxe

C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/8,0,0/src/lime/media/AudioSource.hx:119: characters 20-28 : lime.media._AudioSource.AudioSourceBackend has no field setPitch
C:/HaxeToolkit/haxe/lib/lime/8,0,0/src/lime/media/AudioSource.hx:114: characters 20-28 : lime.media._AudioSource.AudioSourceBackend has no field getPitch

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try Lime 7.9.0 and OpenFL 9.1.0

Comment: source/Achievements.hx:132: characters 30-54 : Warning : `FlxCamera.defaultCameras` is deprecated, use `FlxG.cameras.setDefaultDrawTarget` instead
C:\FNF-PsychEngine-main\export\release\windows\obj>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
Warning: Could not find Visual Studio 2017 VsDevCmd
Missing HXCPP_VARS
Error: Could not automatically setup MSVC

Comment: another problem

Comment: Do you have installed MS VC? https://github.com/ninjamuffin99/Funkin/issues/190

Answer (score -2):

Hehe! Install Lime 8.0.0!

Because PE (Psych Engine) recently updated to Lime 8.0.0.

haxelib install lime 8.0.0